# Why is the contrast calculated in i1Profiler so low?

Tags: color-management, contrast, lcd, icc-profile

I just received a Dell S3221QS 32" Monitor  with a VA panel.

I used i1 Display Pro and i1Profiler 3.x to calibrate the monitor. At the end the calculated contrast ratio is just 256:1, which is very poor.

I tried different settings, like D65 vs native, 120 cd vs native, table vs matrix, small vs large patch set, lights in the room on or off (in the evening) but I always get the same result, which oscillates between 255.xxx:1 to 256.xxx:1

I tried to use the test on [Lagom](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/contrast_ratio.php) to use my camera to measure the contrast ratio, and I got about 2000:1, which makes more sense for a VA panel.

**Why is the value provided by i1Profiler so low?** (and wrong)

I remember that my previous monitor (*Dell UP2414Q, IPS gb-r display*) used to achieve 850-950:1 with i1Profiler 1.x, which was a more reasonable value.

Why the change in the values?

[image]

Comment: Is that the curved monitor? Might be light leaking in from the room. Have you tried profiling with the lights off?

Comment: @doug I tested that too, I'll update the question. Also, the measurement with a camera produced much higher and realistic values...

Comment: That's really a remarkably low ratio. Especially for that monitor which has a pretty large dynamic range. I looked a Lagom and their technique using a camera is reasonable.

Comment: If we are to believe any of these numbers, it is the black luminance that appears to be suspiciously high. If it shows the same number at night with lights off (note even the keyboard lighting and other such fancy stuff can affect the black reading if there is a leak), there may be an issue either with the display or with the colorimeter, or the method. I would try to profile another monitor with _exactly_ the same settings (software and device), ideally connected to the same computer.

Comment: @Zeus I'll try to profile my old monitor sometime. Leaks from the sides are unlikely, since the colorimeter is pretty well sealed and the only way to get light in is through a very shallow angle, which would also result in a remarkable low fraction being diffused up towards the sensor. Lagom via JPG (50 mm focal, dark room, lens close to the screen) gave me something like 0.045 cd/m^2, if I remember correctly. And lagom took the whole picture as reference, which results in worse values because the corners are brighter due to VA panels (black level increases with viewing angle from vertical).

Comment: I wonder whether I can calculate the maximum contrast from the ICC profile generated by either i1Profiler or DisplayCal.